# Interesting question, but could be improved

Tags: discussion

I'm new here and treading lightly. I think this question touches on interesting and important subjects, but I think the question is confusing and could be worded better:

[Do minimum wage laws disproportionately harm black employment?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10182/do-minimum-wage-laws-create-employment-conditions-that-are-racially-biased-again)

*"Do minimum wage laws create employment conditions that are racially biased against blacks?"*
The word 'bias' ("inclination of temperament or outlook;...") to describe the effects of a law seems to be an incorrect usage of the word.

The question also begins with a grammtically incorrect sentence that I find unclear:
*"There is a common claim that the effect of applying minimum wage laws is the impact the poorer members of society, and thus impact poorer minorities, such as blacks, more than others. "*

I thought about working on the question, but would not touch it in its current state.

Comment: What is your concern with the current state?  It is a political football surely and no answer is going to make everyone happy you will PO 20-30% by showing one way or the other.